# FDSQLiteBackup Sqlite Unable to open database

Tags: android, sqlite, delphi, firedac

I try backup SqLite database in Android with FDSQLiteBackup component with Firedac in Delphi 10.3.3 I can connect Sqlite Db with this command:
TFDConnection SharedCache=False  LockingMode=Normal

```
fdconnection1.Connected:=false;

{$IF DEFINED(IOS) or DEFINED(ANDROID)}
fdconnection1.Params.Values['Database']:=TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath,'mydb.s3db');  
{$ENDIF}

fdconnection1.Connected:=true;
```

But When I try to backup with this command:

```
{$IF DEFINED(IOS) or DEFINED(ANDROID)}
DataM.fdBaglan.Connected:=false;

with datam.FDSQLiteBackup1 do
begin
  database:=TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath,'mydb.s3db');

  DestDatabase:=TPath.Combine(TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath,'backup.s3db');

  backup;
  ShowMessage('ok');
end;
```

It gives error :Unable to open database

Thank you for developing.

Comment: The error may be for the target database. Try using the same directory to test.

Comment: You are right Itried to same database and it works but. Just created database without tables and data that including